# Full circle with symbol like smiling mouth in notification bar

Tags: applications, notification-bar, notification-icons

Does anybody know, what is this icon in the notification bar in the top left corner?

[image: notification bar icon top left]

I saw it on screenshot, thats why I cant check it on my mobile phone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it. Its Android application - Breaking News notification icon.

Comment: Which breaking news application? What is the name?

Comment: "Breaking News" is the name of the notification icon.